# Applying np.apply_along_axis to replace indices with labels

Tags: numpy, apply

I'm trying to replace indices within an array with corresponding labels. I'm able to do it with one line of the array, but am getting all sorts of error trying to apply across the array with np.apply_along_axis. From incorrect syntax to 'item not iterable'

[image]

Comment: `apply_along_axis` isn't worth the effort - unless `x` is 3d or larger (where it simplifies writing a double nested iteration).  Just use plain iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

1. As @hpaulj said in the comment, there really is no point using `apply_along_axis` in this case.
2. If you really do want to use `apply_along_axis`, the problem with your code is that in `label_func`, `x` is already 1-dimensional, so each `i` in `x` is an integer. `[... for idx in i]` therefore gives a `TypeError` because an integer is not iterable. It should have been:

```
def label_func(x):
    return [feature_names[idx] for idx in x]
```

3. This doesn't affect the result, but from your code it looks like you are trying to apply `label_func` along the rows. If so, the `axis` argument in `apply_along_axis` should be 1 because `axis` is the axis along which the array is sliced. This not a problem in this case, but you may run into issues using it this way in the future.
4. Please describe your code and errors with text, not a picture, and include the full stack trace :)